# Why some laser diodes have angled window?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, fiber-optics, laser-cavity

Why some laser diodes have angled window? Here is an example[image]

Comment: That's a Kss-151a (or compatible) used by Sony in their CD drives. I don't know why Sony chose to use an angled window, but in any case that's an engineering/design question not a physics question.

Comment: Quote from the [Meta on engineering questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4536/169454): "Questions about the physical reasoning and analysis that lead to design decisions are on topic; questions seeking help designing or building something is off topic." I vote to re-open.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic If I look at the questions over there dealing with lasers and laser diodes, I would say no. I'm almost certain that the reason for the angled window is optical rather than electronical. Most likely it should prevent back-reflection of the light into the diode. Similar as for [angle-cleaved optical fibers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/tutorial_passive_fiber_optics5.html#:~:text=relevance%20of%20cleave%20angles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angled optical window is also called a Brewster window and it has two functions:

1. Virtually eliminating or greatly reducing the light being
   reflected back to the laser by utilizing Brewster's angle, in
   order to prevent interference with the operation of the laser.
2. Maximizing the amount of light exiting the laser diode by using
   Brewster's angle and thus eliminating losses associated with
   back-reflections from the surface of the optical window.

Brewster windows are also used in other types of lasers such as for example He-Ne laser.

https://www.rp-photonics.com/optical_windows.html
https://www.rp-photonics.com/brewster_windows.html
https://www.rp-photonics.com/brewster_s_angle.html

Comment: Worth adding Wikipedia link [Brewster's angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle)

Comment: I believe this answer is correct, but what is the source of the quoted section: "1. Virtually eliminating or …"?

Comment: @ David Bailey Source added to the answer.